# Hahn decomposition of measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading a proof of Hahn decomposition from Bogachev's Measure Theory. I rewrite the proof to enforce my understanding. I'm pleased to receive your suggestions.

---

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal B(X)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu$ be a finite signed Borel measure on $X$. A set $B \in \mathcal B(X)$ is called *negative* (resp. *positive*) if $\mu(C\cap B) \le 0$ (resp. $\mu(C\cap B) \ge 0$) for all $C \in \mathcal B(X)$.

> **Theorem:** There are $N, P\in \mathcal B(X)$ such that $N \cap P =\emptyset, N \cup P = X$ and that $N,P$ are negative and positive respectively.

I post the proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal N$ be the collection of all negative sets. Notice that $\mathcal N$ is closed under countable union and countable intersection. Let $\alpha := \inf \{\mu(B) \mid B \in \mathcal N\}$. Let $(N_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal N$ such that $\mu(N_n) \searrow \alpha$. Let $N := \bigcup_n N_n$. Clearly, $N$ is negative and thus $N \in \mathcal N$. We have $\alpha \le \mu(N) \le \mu(N_n)$, so $\mu(N) = \alpha$.

Let $P := X \setminus N$. We will prove that $P$ is a positive. Assume the contrary that $P$ is not positive. Then $\exists B_0 \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B_0 \subset P$ and $\mu (B_0)<0$. Then $B_0$ is not negative, so $\exists B \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B \subset B_0$ and $\mu (B)>0$.

- We pick the smallest $k_1 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\exists B_1 \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B_1 \subset B_0$ and $\mu (B_1) \ge 1/k_1$. Then $\mu(B_0\setminus B_1)<0$. Then $B_0\setminus B_1$ is not negative, so $\exists B \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B \subset B_0 \setminus B_1$ and $\mu (B)>0$.
- We pick the smallest $k_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\exists B_2 \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B_2 \subset B_0 \setminus B_1$ and $\mu (B_2) \ge 1/k_2$. Then $\mu(B_0\setminus B_1\setminus B_2)<0$. Then $B_0\setminus B_1 \setminus B_2$ is not negative, so $\exists B \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B \subset B_0 \setminus B_1 \setminus B_2$ and $\mu (B)>0$.

Inductively, $\exists B_{n+1} \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $B_{n+1} \subset B_0 \setminus B_1 \setminus \cdots \setminus B_n$ and $\mu(B_{n+1})>1/k_{n+1}$. Clearly, $k_n \to \infty$. If not, $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n) = \infty$.

Let $C := \bigcup_{n \ge 1} B_n \subset B_0$. Then $\mu(C) >0$. We claim that $B_0 \setminus C$ is negative. If not, $\exists D \in \mathcal B(X)$ s.t. $D \subset B_0 \setminus C$ and $\mu (D)>0$. Take $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $\mu(D) > 1/M$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{k_N-1} \le  \frac{1}{k_{N}} + \frac{1}{M} \le \mu(B_N \cup D).
$$

This contradicts the minimality of $k_N$, so $B_0\setminus C$ is negative. This contradicts the minimality of $\alpha$. Hence $P$ is positive.

---

Let $(N', P')$ be another Hahn decomposition of $\mu$. Let $B \in \mathcal B(X)$. Then
$$
\mu(B\cap N) = \mu(B\cap N\cap N') + \mu(B\cap N \cap P') =   \mu(B\cap N\cap N').
$$
By symmetry, $\mu(B\cap N') = \mu(B\cap N\cap N')$. So $\mu(B\cap N) = \mu(B\cap N')$. Similarly, $\mu(B\cap P) = \mu(B\cap P')$.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me why you made this post (no explicit question in it) just to give yourself the answer immediately afterwards. Did you promise someone to do this? Anyway, it was very **helpful** for me. I was reading the proof in Halmos' Measure Theory (where the hypotheses are more general, making certain things slightly more complicated) ... Your proof resembles very much to that of Halmos, but it continues differently exactly at the point where I couldn't follow Halmos any more. BTW he doesn't make clear why the k_N have to be taken minimal. Your argument fill the gap. Thanks

Comment: To continue with Halmos' proof: I even wonder if it is correct ... may-be he had it from somewhere and didn't correctly reproduce it. BUT the edition I am  using (borrowed from a library) being quite old - apparently the 1st - he might have corrected this in new editions

Comment: BUT there are *little errors* (may-be simple typos) in your text that made it a bit more difficult for me to verify that part of the proof. $\mu(C)$ isn't <0, on the contrary it is >=0. But that seems to be useless anyway. It should say  $\mu(B_0\C)$ <0. Then where you write $\mu(B_N union C)$ there should be a $D$ instead of the $C$

Comment: In case I don't receive soon an answer, I will try to correct the errors myself by editing your answer or - in case I haven't yet the priviledge this might need - , enter a second answer with the corrections in it as is often done

Comment: @UlysseKeller Thank you so much for your elaboration! You are right! I have corrected the typos.

Comment: Good. I conjecture that there is more to be done so that the average math' reader will understand your proof. I guess I would have had myself problems with it, if I hadn't read Halmos' proof before. This is more explicit until the point where you define the set $C$. After that his proof appears to me as opaque if not even incorrect, and there your text helped me. The thing is that an argument ending with "This contradicts the minimality of $\alpha$" is needed at several places. Having in all occurrences the same "mechanic" it suffices to be shown once (*continued*)

Comment: (then Halmos writes "the argument just applied to *** is applicable to +++" where the two triple special signs stand for set names that I don't make explicit because your names are anyway different) ... First occurrence is in the paragraph where you say "Assume (...) that P is not positive". Each time you write "Then %%% is not negative" with %%% standing for some set, an argument of the type mentioned is missing; in it a set union with N plays a role (providing a set with measure more negative than N). And just before you say "Hence P is positive" it is $B_0 slash C$ that should not be neg.

Comment: but this time it IS negative, which produces the final clash, producing the last contradiction in this *nested* system of proofs by contradiction, the one that surrounds the others. And for that, it would be better - insteaad of only changing the inequaliy sign in the comparison between $\mu(C)$ and 0 - to replace the measured set $C$ by $B0 backslash C$ (and restoring the original <)

Comment: BTW where I put "slash" in my comment, it should read also "backslash" and $B0$ in the last comment should again be $B_0$

Comment: Do you dislike my proposal for more changes to this Question of this Q & A item? If so, only because of the work necessary? In this case would you suggest that I do the work myself?

Comment: @UlysseKeller I think it's better that you post a new question and your elaboration as an answer.

Comment: I will not do that because it would probably be qualified as a duplicate

Comment: @UlysseKeller I agree. Maybe you can create a personal website (that supports Mathjax) to post your learning progress.

Comment: I might only add a second answer to complete yours - to make this Q & A item here more useful to 3rd parties ... That's all for the moment in this website. For my study I'll continue with what I mentioned as motivation in my own question having title beginning with *When all Borel subsets of a Borel set B*. BTW your Q. has the same restricted hypotheses as are in *that* one (different conclusion, but a proof using Hahn decomp. which I eventually found myself and posted as answer in this site) except that I also state as hyp. that X is loc. compact. My curiosity: what was *your* source?

Comment: @UlysseKeller it's from Bogachev's Measure Theory.

Answer (score 0):

It may help some readers of the first answer to add some more details.

In the paragraph of that answer beginning with Let *P:=X∖N*, the conclusion that $B_0$ is not negative may not be obvious. It is obtained like this: if this set *were* negative, then $\mu(B_0 \cup N) = \mu(B_0) + \mu(N) < \alpha$ because $B_0$ and $N$ are disjoint and $\mu(B_0) < 0$, contradicting the minimality of $\alpha$.

In the next two paragraphs, there are similar conclusions about some set *not* being negative; these are obtained in the same way.

Then in the paragraph beginning with the definition of $C$, it is true that $\mu(C)>0$ but what really matters here is that $\mu(B_0 \setminus C)<0$. When after that it is shown that $B_0 \setminus C$ is indeed negative, a similar argument shows again a contradiction with the minimality of $\alpha$ (as stated explicitely this time in the 1st answer), this being the last contradiction leading to the conclusion that $P$ is positive (as stated there).

And then there is something else that might confuse a reader of the 1st answer, but which a smart one will be able to correct himself. It is the fact that the letter $N$ is used in two different contexts with different roles. First it is a set as constructed in the first paragraph of the proof. Towards the end, it is a natural number - which by the way must be non-zero (no $k_0$ has been defined).

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Analyst how do you appreciate this?