# Reconcile the weak and weak$^*$ topologies of $\mathcal P(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence, borel-measures, weak-topology

I'm trying to strengthen my understanding between these two topologies of $\mathcal P(E)$. Could you have a check on my below exposition?

---

Let

- $X$ be a normal Hausdorff topological space,
- $E :=C_b (X)$ the space of all real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$,
- $C_0 (X)$ the space of all real-valued continuous functions on $X$ that vanish at infinity,
- $C_c (X)$ the space of all real-valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact supports,
- $\mathcal P(X)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$, and
- $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all finite signed Borel measures on $X$.

We endow $E$ with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Then $(E, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a Banach space and $C_0 (X)$ its closed subspace. Also, $C_c (X)$ is **not** generally closed in $(E, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$. Let $\mu, \mu_n \in \mathcal P(X)$ for all $n \ge 1$.

- We define the **weak topology** of $\mathcal P(X)$ as the one induced by the convergence (denoted by $\rightharpoonup$) criterion
  $$
  \mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm \mu \quad \forall f \in E.
  $$
- We define the **weak$^*$ topology** of $\mathcal P(X)$ as the one induced by the convergence (denoted by $\overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}$) criterion
  $$
  \mu_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm \mu \quad \forall f \in C_0 (X).
  $$

1. Because the closure of $C_c (X)$ in $(E, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is $C_0 (X)$, we have
   $$
   \mu_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \iff \int_X f \mathrm \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm \mu \quad \forall f \in C_c (X).
   $$
2. Let $E^*$ be the continuous dual space of $E$, and $\sigma(E^*, E)$ the weak$^*$ topology of $E^*$. We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440407/the-space-of-finite-signed-measures-with-the-total-variation-norm-is-a-banach-sp) a Banach space. There [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923330/duality-pairing-between-finite-signed-measures-and-bounded-continuous-functions) an isometric embedding
   $$
   \varphi:\mathcal M(X) \to E^*, \mu \mapsto \varphi(\mu),
   $$
   defined by
   $$
   \langle  \varphi(\mu), f \rangle :=\int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in E.
   $$

Then the weak topology of $\mathcal P(X)$ is the subspace topology that $\sigma(E^*, E)$ induces on $\varphi [\mathcal P(X)]$.

3. Let $F:=C_0(X)$. Then $F$ is a Banach space. We define a map
   $$
   \psi:\mathcal P(X) \to F^*, \mu \mapsto \psi(\,u)
   $$
   by
   $$
    \langle  \psi(\mu), f \rangle :=\int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in F.
   $$

Because $F$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959431/the-continuous-functions-of-compact-support-are-dense-in-l1) dense in $(E, \|\cdot\|_{L_1})$, we get $\psi$ is injective. Clearly, $\mu_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ if and only if $\psi(\mu_n) \to \psi(\mu)$ in the weak$^*$ topology $\sigma(F^*, F)$ of $F^*$.