# Does $\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ necessarily imply $\mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$?

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology, signed-measures

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all finite **signed** Borel measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ be the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$, and
- $\mathcal C_0(X)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ that vanish at infinity.

Then $\mathcal C_b(X)$ and $\mathcal C_0(X)$ are real Banach space with supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ [is a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440407/the-space-of-finite-signed-measures-with-the-total-variation-norm-is-a-banach-sp). Let $\mathcal M(X)^* := (\mathcal M(X))^*$ and $\mathcal C_b(X)^* := (\mathcal C_b(X))^*$ be the continuous duals. Let $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$.

- We define the first type of weak convergence by
  $$
  \mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_b(X),
  $$
  Let $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_b(X))$ be the topology induced by $\overset{1}{\rightharpoonup}$.
- We define the second type of weak convergence by
  $$
  \mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \varphi(\mu_n) \to \varphi (\mu) \quad \forall \varphi \in \mathcal M(X)^*,
  $$
  Let $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal M(X)^*)$ be the topology induced by $\overset{2}{\rightharpoonup}$.

Then we have

> **Theorem:** If $\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ then $\{[\mu_n] \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded.
>
> *Proof:*  It's well-known [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3938193/1019043)
> $$
> \mathcal M(X) \to \mathcal C_b(X)^*, \nu \mapsto \left (L_\nu :f \mapsto \int_X f \mathrm d \nu \right).
> $$
> is an isometrically isomorphic embedding. This implies $[\nu] = \|L_\nu\|$. By [uniform boundedness principle](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Theorem), it suffices to show that $(L_{\mu_n} (f))_n$ is bounded for each $f \in  \mathcal C_b(X)$. This is indeed true because $L_{\mu_n} (f) \to L_{\mu} (f)$ for each $f \in \mathcal C_b(X)$. This completes the proof.

**My question:**

> Does $\mu_n \overset{1}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ necessarily imply $\mu_n \overset{2}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$? If not, what if $X$ is locally compact (and possibly separable)?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Since $\mathcal M(X)=C_b(X)^*$, what you are asking is whether weak$^*$-convergence implies weak convergence. Are you particular about using sequences and not nets for convergence?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I maybe wrong but $\mathcal M(X) \neq \mathcal C_b(X)^*$ in general. I'm fine with using net.

Comment: Yes, you probably need locally compact , I missed that. Now, my (poor) intuition is that if what you have is just that $X$ is a metric space, $C_b(X)$ can be pretty nasty, and I would expect no relation between $C_0(X)$ and $C_b(X)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yeah I'm ready to assume $X$ is locally compact (and possibly separable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While they might not be the exact same thing, in spirit you are comparing weak and weak$^*$ convergence.

Let $X=[0,1]$ (the example works exactly the same if we take $X=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:\ n\}$), $$\mu_n=\delta_{1/n},\qquad\qquad \mu=\delta_{\{0\}}.$$ For any $f\in C_b(X)$,
$$
\int_Xf\,d\mu_n=f\big(\frac1n\big)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f(0)=\int_Xf\,d\mu. 
$$
Now let $\varphi\in M(X)^*$ be given by $\varphi(\eta)=\eta(\{0\})$. This is linear, and bounded since $|\eta(\{0\})|\leq|\eta(X)|\leq\|\eta\|$. And
$$
\varphi(\mu_n)=0,\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb N,
$$
while
$$
\varphi(\mu)=\delta_{\{0\}}(\{0\})=1. 
$$
What happens is that in the #$1$ convergence you are testing against continuous functions, while in the #$2$ convergence you are testing against all bounded Borel functions and possibly more; this is a stronger notion of convergence.

Comment: The second type is weak convergence. Weak convergence is stronger than weak$^*$-convergence. What the example shows is that weak$^*$-convergence is strictly weaker than weak convergence (that is, an example of a weak$^*$-convergent sequence that does not converge weakly).